# Why thread not going into waiting status for infinite time?

Tags: java, multithreading

Below is the code piece which successfully finishes the execution when I run it in my local machine.

I cannot understand why this thread is not going into infinite wait status ?

```
public class Job extends Thread {

    private int counter;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                counter++;
            }

            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Job job = new Job();
        job.start();
        synchronized (job) {
            job.wait();
        }

        System.out.println(job.counter);
    }
}
```

Is there any gurantee that above code will always finish execution in every condition ? Can anybody clarify ?

Comment: wait|() can wake spuriously without a notify.  This is why you should always change a state in a synchronized block with notify and always change the state change in a loop with wait()  With you code, there is no guarantees one way or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure looks like you have a [`Race Condition`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) on your hands - it all depends on which `synchronized(job)` happens first - the one in your main thread or the one in the job.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities

1. The main Thread enters the `synchronized` first and `wait()`s. In this case, the program will terminate because the `job` `Thread` will call `notify()` on the `synchronized` object.
2. The `job` `Thread` enters the `synchronized` block first and calls `notify()` before the main `Thread` calls `wait()`, ie. main `Thread` can't because it waits at the `synchronized` block. This will block the application as the main `Thread` will not be able to return from the `wait()` call.

Comment: Wouldn't a sleep on the job's run method cause the deadlock?

Comment: @zmbq I don't think so, because when it switches contexts, the other other thread is still waiting, so it will switch back.

Comment: Only one thread can enter the `synchronized` block concurrently, right? If the job does, all is well (the job runs the loop, notifies and exits). If it's the main thread, the job won't be able run. Am I missing something?

Comment: @zmbq No, you got it. I think that's what I wrote in my question. That if the main Thread sleeps, the job Thread will enter and finish its synchronized. It will notify before the main thread `wait()`s

Comment: Keep in mind the wait method will release the ownership of the synchronized object before blocking. I think that's the link you are missing.

Comment: A deadlock situation requires at least two locks.

Comment: @Bowmore You are correct, this isn't deadlock in the sense of two threads wanting eachothers resources. But the program won't advance from the point it happens.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot understand why this thread is not going into infinite wait
>   status ?

It can, and it will happen if `this.notifyAll()` is called before `job.wait()`.

Add a flag to test for completion, something like the following:

```
public class Job extends Thread {

    private int counter;
    private boolean finished = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                counter++;
            }

            finished = true;
            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Job job = new Job();
        job.start();
        synchronized (job) {
            while (!job.finished)
                job.wait();
        }

        System.out.println(job.counter);
    }
}
```

That way you can guarantee that the program will not run into a race condition and will wait forever. Also note that you are now protected against [spurious wakeups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the spurious wakeup issues (which should not affect this simple use most of the time), you should expect that code to always finish.

One thing you seem to be missing is that `job.wait();` releases the lock, enabling the other `synchronized` block to be executed and `notifyAll()` to be called. At that point, `wait` wakes up and the main method exits.